# Show link if any text input is not empty

Tags: jquery

I'd like to reveal a link as the user starts to fill any of the text inputs inside `div class="filters"`. The link should only be hidden when all fields are empty/have the default values provided in the HTML.

This is the code so far:

```
<div class="filters">
  <input type="text" id="firstname_filter" value="Filter">
  <input type="text" id="lastname_filter" value="Filter">
  <input type="text" id="cellphone_filter" value="Filter">
  <a class="clear-filters" style="display:none;">Clear all filters</a>
</div>
```

```js
init_vals = new Array();

//save default value of each input
$("filters input").each( function (i) {
    init_vals[i] = this.value;
});

//clear default value on field focus
$("filters input").focus(function () {
    this.value = "";
});

//set default value on blur if field is empty
$("filters input").blur(function (i) {
    if (this.value == "") {
        this.value = init_vals[$("filters input").index(this)];
    }
});

//if any input is not blank, show the link
$("filters input").bind('change keyup', function(el, index) {
    if ($("filters input").map(function(idx, elem) { 
        if ( $(elem).val() != "" ) return $(elem);
    }).size() > 0) {
        $(".clear-filters").show();
    } else {
        $(".clear-filters").hide();
    }
});
```

When I start typing in one of the text inputs, the link shows up. However when I clear that same field, the link doesn't disappear because **all other fields have the default values set**. Any tips on how to ignore default values when checking if the fields are empty?

Thank you.

Comment: You could use [Placeholder content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) instead of a value for the default value

Comment: I'm not using it due to compatibility issues in IE.

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that you need a period in front of each `filters` class selector. `$(".filters ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to check for the default value when you check if the field is blank.

```
//if any input is not blank, show the link
$(".filters input").bind('change keyup', function(el, index) {
  if ($(".filters input").map(function(idx, elem) { 
    if ( $(elem).val() != ""&& $(elem).val() != init_vals[idx] ) // updated
      return $(elem);
  }).size() > 0) {
    ...
```

https://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/pfLtz1p3/

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use [`placeholder`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-placeholder) and `reset` buttons:

```js
$(function () {
  $("#reset").prop("disabled", true).click(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
      $("#reset").prop("disabled", true);
    }, 100);
  });
  $("input").change(function () {
    $("input").each(function () {
      if ($(this).val().trim().length > 0)
        $("#reset").prop("disabled", false);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="filters">
  <input type="text" id="firstname_filter" placeholder="Filter" />
  <input type="text" id="lastname_filter" placeholder="Filter" />
  <input type="text" id="cellphone_filter" placeholder="Filter" />
  <input type="reset" value="Clear All" id="reset" />
</form>
```

Comment: He is clearly saying that


   
 
I'm not using it due to compatibility issues in IE.